# Can you disable the standby mode on a Macbook Air 2010 model?

Tags: macos, macbook-air

It seems that the Macbook Air 2010 model has some issues waking from its standby mode which it goes into after an hour of on-battery sleep.  I'm looking for a way to disable this standby behavior.  I'm sure there's a plist file somewhere that will turn it off but I can't find it for the life of me.  Anyone have any ideas/hints?

Answer (score 1):

Caffeine will not stop the computer from sleeping when the lid is closed (this comes form experience, I use it daily), for this you will want InsomniaX http://roaringapps.com/app:1281

Naturally, if you still want it to sleep when the lid is closed, then Caffenine would be the better solution as detailed in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just run [Caffeine](http://www.lightheadsw.com/caffeine/).

> Caffeine is a tiny program that puts an icon in the right side of your
>   menu bar. Click it to prevent your Mac from automatically going to
>   sleep, dimming the screen or starting screen savers. Click it again to
>   go back. Right-click the icon to show the menu.

Answer (score 0):

To disable standby / "deep sleep", run the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo pmset -a standby 0
```

See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60634/disable-stand-by-mode-on-retina-macbook-pro) for more information.